# What are differences between "during" and "while"?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, word-difference

> They arrived while we were having dinner.

Can I use "during" instead of "while" in that sentence? How about this sentence:

> Would you look after the children while I do the shopping?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The meanings are similar but I'm finding it hard to think of an instance where you could simply exchange the two words without restructuring the sentence.

> They arrived while we were having dinner

could be expresses as:

> They arrived during our dinner

and:

> Would you look after the children while I do the shopping?

would become:

> Would you look after the children during my shopping trip?

After analyzing your two examples, it seems like *during* precedes a noun, but *while* precedes a verbal phrase. This makes sense, because *during* is a preposition, but – when used to mean *"during the time that"* – *while* is a conjunction.

Here are some more examples where I try to exchange the two words:

> He sprained his ankle during the **game**.
> He sprained his ankle while **playing** the game.
>
> I can't concentrate on my homework during the television **show**.
> I can't concentrate on my homework while the TV show **is** on.
>
> I started to get scared during the **thunderstorm**.
> I started to get scared while the thunderstorm **was raging**.

The word *while* is more likely to be interchangeable with the word *as*:

> I started to get scared **as** the thunderstorm was raging.

Comment: I see it like this: _During_ always applies to an event that takes a certain amount of time. _While_ applies to a condition that must be met. That condition, in this question, is "that the aforementioned event is in progress". That is why the while version needs a verb to indicate activity (playing, is on, was raging) while during can just mention the event itself (game, show, thunderstorm).

Answer (score 0):

"During" is a preposition with a noun following as in "during the war".
"While" is a conjunction with a clause following" ... while we were in Spain.